# Is old subpanel wiring configuration to code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, subpanel

I opened an old subpanel and this is how it is wired. The fuses are all 30 amp, tube-style fuses.

[image]

1. What is the purpose of connecting the two left-most lugs?
2. Is that intended to increase amps?
3. Is this to code?

Assuming feeder is rated to 120 V/60 amps, and fuses are 30 amps, would connecting the two left-most fuses with a single wire out, create a 120 V/ 60 A hot wire?

Alternatively, if there were two separate, single wires out below those fuses, would this just be how they created two 120 V/30 A hot wires?

Comment: If it is wired up like that, feeder 1 is hot/live and is supplying both hot buses/bars and feeder 2 is neutral.  All 30 amp fuses is the problem unless they are powering hot water tanks or other sub panels.  30 amps is too much on normal household circuits.  They should be maybe 15 amp max unless the wires are 12 gauge or bigger.  A picture of the panel will help.

Comment: @crip659 Sorry for disappearing. This is going to a well pump that needs 230V and 30 amps. Can't seem to get a picture to upload. The pump is fed from the two outside buses. The middle one is not being used. I was just trying to figure out how this panel might have been used before it's current configuration.